# Detect Activity being paused due to configuration change?

Tags: android

I have an application that plays and records audio throw a background service.
I'm trying to pause the process when the activity onPause method is called. but I don't want it to be paused when the configuration is changed "which will call onPause" .
any ideas how to do that , without the need to handle activity's configuration change manually ?

Thanks,

Comment: when configuration is changed.. onDestroy() is the method which is called..

Comment: I need to handle the event in the onPause method "to stop the audio" can't use onDestroy which may or may not be called

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with `API11` or above, you have the [isChangingConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29) method.

Comment: Thanks , but no I'm targeting API level 8